# How to change the Members of two Planners in the same Site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-planner, planner

I have a SharePoint team site, and I've created two different Plans with the **Planner web part.**
When I'm in the charts section I realized both plans have as members the people that I added as members in the home site of my SharePoint page. Is the list that appear in this screenshot, it says it has 11 members.

[image]

But I want those people to have access to one Planner and other different people to have access to the second planner.
People from the first Planner shouldn't be allowed to the second one!

Answer (score 0):

You have to break inheritance on the list permissions, add the people you want to have access and remove the others.

Comment: But where exactly do I have to add the permissions for the Planner? When I go to "Site Permissions > Advanced permissions settings" and break the inheritance there, the planners still have as members the people that appear in the screenshot that I showed above, people from *Group membership* list, and those people doesn't appear in any other group.

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you were saying and was looking at it as site permissions.  Didn't realize it was one webpart on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible as Planner is tied to the M365 Group Members. If you have two Plans attached to the same M365 Group, all members of that single M365 Group will have access.

The solution would be to add your second Plan to a different M365 Group. You can add an arbitrary M365 Group to the SharePoint Members group to maintain access to the site itself.